# jquery, not finding children

Tags: jquery, debugging, children

Something has happened so that when I try to find an elements children I am returned an empty array.  My first thought was I didn't have closing tags, but it seemed all was fine.  So I stripped everything out of the div except one simple element.  When I log this:

```
$(this.el)
```

I get this:

```
[<div class=​"sticker" id=​"sticker-id-15">​]
    <div class=​"hello">​</div>​
</div>​
```

however if I log this:

```
$(this.el).children();
```

I'm returned with an empty array.

Are there any other debugging thoughts that should be coming to mind? I'm drawing a blank...

Comment: How are you calling `$(this.el)`? What is `this` a reference to?

Comment: added js fiddle to my answer, dont really understand what your trying to do as @Terric question is unanswered hope it helps!

Comment: this is referencing a backbone view.  When I cas $(this.el) it is referencing the views dom element.

Comment: Where did those brackets come from ?

Comment: that is what console.log() outputs it as in chrome

Answer (score 1):

Should it not be

```
 $('#sticker-id-15').children().each(function(){
//code for each child
});
```

Or

```
 $('#sticker-id-15').children();
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XuZBt/23/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/captDaylight/m3Jmr/  here is the fiddle, children() should return an array of the children elements.  in this fiddle it is returning '.inner'.

Comment: @captDaylight erm... yeah and in your jsfiddle it's returning `<div class="inner" />` which is correct as it's the only child element. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Terric, yes I think you are, my question is saying that for some reason class 'hello' is not being returned when I query .children() on $(this.el).  $(this.el) IS returning the whole thing when I log it by itself, but it's not returning the correct results when I add .children() to it as is working in my jsfiddle.  the fiddle is just an example of how it should work.

Comment: Could you make an exact fiddle with your issue, and ill try solve it